# Need help to convert decimal to hexadecimal without using functios like bin() or hex()

Tags: python

Ok, first time posting anything here, so here we go

I just started to learn programming, and my professor gave us that huge impossible problem (at least for me lol) to do a base converter without using function like bin() or hex().

```
Bin -> Dec, Hex, Oct 

Dec -> Bin, Hex, Oct

Hex -> Bin, Dec, Oct

Oct -> Bin, Dec, Hex
```

I was able to code (I think) 3 of these so far (binary to decimal, decimal to binary and decimal to octal), but I cant seem to find a way to do the DECIMAL to HEXADECIMAL. That's what I've got so far (all in python)

```py
    # BINARY TO DECIMAL
    binary_value = int(input("Write a binary value: "))
    bits = list(str(binary_value))
    bin_to_decimal_value = 0
    counter = 0

    for x in reversed(bits):
        bin_to_decimal_value += 2 ** counter * int(x)
        counter += 1

    print(f"{binary_value} is equal to {bin_to_decimal_value} in decimal")


    # DECIMAL TO BINARY
    def dec_to_bin(num):
        if num > 1:
            dec_to_bin(num // 2)
        print(num % 2, end='')


    dec_val = int(input("Write a decimal value: "))
    dec_to_bin(dec_val)
    print("\n")


    # DECIMAL TO OCTAL
    def dec_to_oct(num):
        if num > 1:
            dec_to_oct(num // 8)
        print(num % 8, end='')


    dec_to_oct(dec_val)
    print("\n")
```

I don't expect you guys to just do it for me, but I would like to know what I should consider to create a DEC to HEX converter, as well as some tips or anything that's useful to code this.

I'm new to programming and Stackoverflow in general, if I did something wrong let me know. xd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this [youtube video](https://video.search.yahoo.com/search/video?fr=yfp-t-s&p=convert+hex+to+decimal#id=2&vid=04a00e64e7b5ce23f3bd34bc406a33f5&action=view), I was able to see how to convert a base 10 number to its hex form. In fact, once I coded it up, I extended it to handle any base 10 conversion to any base (base 2, base 8 base 16).

I don't have a very good grasp on recursive functions, so I can't comment on your recursive solutions for converting base 10 to base 8 or base 2.

I created 2 functions: `base2dec(num, base)` and `dec2base(dec, base)` that did the conversions.

To convert, for example from base 16 to base 8, it was suggested on a youtube video, to first convert base 16 to base 10 and then from base 10 to base 8.

If I can offer any more information, please feel free to ask.

EDIT: I tried one of your recursive functions for dec to hex, and it seems to work ok but sometimes puts a leading zero in the result. I can't tell why.

```
def dec_to_hex(num):
    d = {i:k for i, k in enumerate('0123456789abcdef')}
    if num > 1:
        dec_to_hex(num // 16)

    print(d[num % 16], end='')

dec_to_hex(255)
```

Prints `0ff` instead of `ff`. Can't see why this happens. When I ran `dec_to_hex(256)` it prints `100`.
`

You can see I created a dictionary `d` which converts say the number 15 to `f`

Lastly, with a minor adjustment, you could have just one function to translate decimal to a base.

```
def dec_to_base(num, base):
    d = {i:k for i, k in enumerate('0123456789abcdef')}
    if num > 1:
        dec_to_hex(num // base)

    print(d[num % base], end='')
```